# How to know which module is responsible for each database query?

Tags: database, debugging

I enable the devel module and set it to **Display query log**.

Then on every page load I get a list of the generated sql queries. You can see an example of that list in the capture I uploaded. So far so good.

Is there any way to know which module is responsible for each database queries (in case that the query is generated by a module)?

If this is not possible. Is there any way to do an analysis of all enabled modules to see how them are affecting the general performance of the site?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any modules you download from [drupal.org](http://drupal.org), you can click on the function link within the **where** column and it will direct you to [api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org) and you can see the module there.

I couldn't find any settings that would enable showing where the call originated (file path) if the module wasn't an 'official' contrib.  A little digging and you can find the information within the devel.module.  Specifically, [`devel_query_table()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/devel_query_table/7) receives `$queries` as its first argument.  `$queries` contains the rows that will be displayed and it does have the file path.

I created a quick patch to test this (Doing this does not imply that i think you should modify contrib modules in a production environment):

```
diff --git a/sites/all/modules/devel/devel.module b/sites/all/modules/devel/devel.module
index 0ebdef4..dd6aaa8 100644
--- a/sites/all/modules/devel/devel.module
+++ b/sites/all/modules/devel/devel.module
@@ -1482,7 +1482,7 @@ function _devel_print_object($obj, $prefix = NULL, $parents = NULL, $object = FA
*/
 function devel_query_table($queries, $counts) {
   $version = devel_get_core_version(VERSION);
 -  $header = array ('ms', '#', 'where', 'ops', 'query', 'target');
 +  $header = array ('ms', '#', 'what', 'ops', 'query', 'target', 'where');
    $i = 0;
   $api = variable_get('devel_api_url', 'api.drupal.org');
   foreach ($queries as $query) {
 @@ -1514,7 +1514,8 @@ function devel_query_table($queries, $counts) {
   'id' => "devel-query-$i",
   'data' => $placeholders . $args . $explain,
 );
 -    $cell[$i][] = $query['target'];
 +    $cell[$i][] = $query['target'];    
 +    $cell[$i][] = '<div style="overflow-x:scroll">' . check_plain($query['caller']['file']) . '</div>';
      $i++;
     unset($diff, $count, $ops);
 }
```

Here is the raw output on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Ww5CkQsL

And a screenshot of the un-styled results:

[image]

This is a little rough looking as there are style sheets involved, but it gets the information.

Even better would be if the **where** column builder checked for the availability of the function on d.o but I'll digress, as I feel we may be entering, 'file an issue (feature request)' territory.

Comment: I tried to use the patch but I get this error message: `git apply -v devel-module-queries.patch
devel-module-queries.patch:10: trailing whitespace.
  $header = array ('ms', '#', 'what', 'ops', 'query', 'target', 'where');
devel-module-queries.patch:19: trailing whitespace.
    $cell[$i][] = $query['target'];
devel-module-queries.patch:20: trailing whitespace.
    $cell[$i][] = '<div style="overflow-x:scroll">' . check_plain($query['caller']['file']) . '</div>';
fatal: corrupt patch at line 23`

Comment: Must just be whitespace from copying/pasting, try this one, which I was able to just apply cleanly: http://pastebin.com/E16gT1w0.

Comment: Same, I get the trailing whitespace errors. Can you post a link to the patch file?

Comment: I've got the patch applied.

Comment: It works fine. Very useful. I was able to find a module which was causing lots of queries. Many thanks Chris.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped.